# Dynamic query using variable number of IN (p1, p2, p3) arguments

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following:

```
Dim strdepToDelete As String
Dim strOtherToDelete As String
strdepToDelete = String.Join(",", depToDelete)
strOtherToDelete = String.Join(",", otherToDelete)
strdepToDelete = strdepToDelete.Replace(Chr(34), Chr(39)).Substring(1, 77)
strOtherToDelete = strOtherToDelete.Replace(Chr(34), Chr(39)).Substring(1, 77)

cmd.CommandText = "delete from database.tableA where guid in(@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete);"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@strdepToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String)
cmd.Parameters("@strdepToDelete").Value = strdepToDelete
cmd.Parameters.Add("@strOtherToDelete", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.String)
cmd.Parameters("@strOtherToDelete").Value = strOtherToDelete
Dim answer = MsgBox("Data will be deleted if you continue", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo + MsgBoxStyle.DefaultButton2, "Are You Sure")
If answer = vbYes Then
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        success = True
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return success
End If
```

I hover over

```
cmd.Parameters("@strdepToDelete").Value = strdepToDelete
```

and

```
cmd.Parameters("@strOtherToDelete").Value = strOtherToDelete
```

and have a string value in format that MySql is looking for. Why are the records not deleted from the table?

Comment: cmd has it's connection set before this?

Comment: Please do not use empty Catch blocks.  If something goes wrong (like no connection) you will never know

Comment: When i hover over cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() the CommandText is delete from database.tableA where guid in(@strdepToDelete, @strOtherToDelete); not the values of the variables

Comment: Yes the connection is set before this

Comment: can you tell us what `depToDelete` and the other holds?  Some of that starting code looks extraneous.  Also you should turn on Option Strict (probably not the issue here, but it will make for better code).  Connection was just one thing - any exception is being swallowed so you cant even know what the problem is.  Also `Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` will tell you how many rows MySql thinks were affected.

Comment: depToDelete and otherToDelete are list(of string) which passes from a function call.  These hold the 1 or many guids that I wish to delete.  rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() returned 0 which is exactly what I thought.  Thanks for the continued suggestions.

Comment: when more than one person has commented, you need to use `@username`  (as in @m.rice) of you want us to get pinged.  You get pinged for all of them because you are the OP.  Your query is malformed if it is a list of strings

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments:

*depToDelete and otherToDelete are list(of string) which passes from a function call. These hold the 1 or many guids that I wish to delete*

For that, your code doesnt format it correctly for the SQL.  For a list of 2 Guid Strings, after the join you get this:

```
"af489fbf-982a-49de-b73e-2ac3f3192225, 0feab28d-4f96-456a-9f36-0a0376627128"
```

Then, `strOtherToDelete = strOtherToDelete.Replace(Chr(34), Chr(39)).Substring(1, 77)` apparently wants to try to remove the quote and replace with a tick.  The problem is that the string itself doesnt include a Quote.  You see it in the IDE because that is VS's way of telling you it is a string.

The `SubString` step is trimming valid Guid chars from the result (and a Magic Number of `77` allows it to crash when there are not just the right number of them):

Before:   `"9b842f14-7932-4e3d-8483-07790ccc674c, ...`
& After:   `"b842f14-7932-4e3d-8483-07790ccc674c,...`

This wont work because the contents are not one very long Guid.  Each *element* in the `List` needs to be ticked.  To tick each element in the list you need to loop and build a string, or use linq.

*But that wont work either.*  MySQL just doesn't like the resulting string from the NET provider that way and it doesnt do parameter arrays so...

#### So lets build a parameters engine:

There is no sense working with 2 sets of Guids, so concat them (these are an actual `List(of String)` containing guids, not something else, not json):

```vb
Dim depVals = depToDelete.Concat(otherToDelete).ToList

' your sql here
Dim sql = "DELETE FROM DEMO WHERE GuidString IN (@magic)"
' param storage
Dim gvalues As New List(Of String)

' create a list of "@g" param placeholders
Dim ndx As Int32 = 0
For ndx = 0 To depVals.Count - 1
    ' adds a "@gN" value to the List
    gvalues.Add(String.Format("@g{0}", (ndx + 1).ToString))
Next

' insert them into the SQL string
sql = sql.Replace("@magic", String.Join(", ", gvalues))
' '@magic' replaced with "@g1, @g2, @g3..." 

Using cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, dbcon)
    dbcon.Open()

    ' create an equal number of Paramerters, set the value of each
    For n As Int32 = 0 To gvalues.Count - 1
       ' add parm "@gN", assign value from 'depVals`
       cmd.Parameters.Add(gvalues(n), MySqlDbType.String).Value = depVals(n)
    Next

   ' debug:
   Dim fullSQL = GetFullCommandSQL(cmd)
   Console.WriteLine(fullSQL)

   Dim rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The debug output is syntactically correct:

> DELETE FROM DEMO WHERE GuidString IN ('2abfa4c4-36e2-47ea-8218-6f568a31fa88', 'fd02865e-5da2-4d4e-ba4b-84bf5b5f1444', '7376d9a3-35c9-4b44-8b85-4cd663b31d5e')

...and the 3 rows with those GUIDs get deleted!

Also:

- Empty Catch blocks are bad because they hide problems from the only person who can fix it (you).
- You should us Option Strict to avoid VB guessing what you mean by certain things.

Comment: Thank you so much.  Who knew.  I broke strings into substrings each 36 and put them in individual parameters in query works like a dream.  Have a great day