# parsing database columns and values to MySQL statement in module

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a dynamic MySQL `INSERT INTO...WHERE NOT EXIST` statement by parsing the table name, array of columns, array of values and conditional column and value to a subroutine in a separate module but i keep hitting the `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` error. Below is the code:

```
Sub InsertRecord(ByVal tbl As String, ByVal cols() As String, ByVal params() As String, _
                      ByVal colCondition As String, ByVal paramCondition As String) 'As String

    'Create new string of columns
    Dim myCols As String = ""
    For Each col As String In cols
        myCols &= col & ", "
    Next

    Dim newCols As String = myCols.Remove(myCols.Count - 2, 2)
    MsgBox(newCols)
    Dim scols As String = newCols.Insert(0, "`").Replace(", ", "`, `") & "`"
    MsgBox(scols)



    'Create new string of parameters
    Dim myParams As String = ""
    For Each param In params
        myParams &= param & ", "
    Next

    Dim newParams As String = myParams.Remove(myParams.Count - 2, 2)
    MsgBox(newParams)
    Dim sparams As String = newParams.Insert(0, "'").Replace(", ", "', '") & "'"
    MsgBox(sparams)
    'End


    Dim p As String = paramCondition.Insert(0, "'") & "'"



    'Try
    'Dim insRemarks As String = "done"
    con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=etms; Uid=root; Pwd=;")
    comA = New MySqlCommand

    'INSERT NEW RECORD.
    'THIS GIVES THE ERROR
    comA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & tbl & " (" & scols & ") SELECT * FROM (SELECT @params) AS tmp "
    comA.CommandText &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT " & colCondition & " FROM " & tbl & " WHERE " & colCondition & " = @param) limit 1"
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", p)
    comA.Parameters.AddWithValue("@params", sparams)



    'THIS STATIC CODE WORKS FINE.
    'comA.CommandText = "INSERT INTO state (`st_state`, `ctry_Id`) SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'a', '1') AS tmp "
    'comA.CommandText &= "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT st_state FROM state WHERE st_state = 'a') limit 1"



    comA.Connection = con

    con.Open()
    comA.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    'Release used up components
    comA.Parameters.Clear()
    comA.Dispose()
    comA = Nothing
    con = Nothing

    MsgBox("done.")

    'Return insRemarks

    'Catch ex As Exception
    'MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & comA.CommandText.ToString)
    'Return "Error"
    'End Try

End Sub
```

As seen, i tried a lot of permutations (introducing inverted quotation marks) to no avail.

I'll be glad if someone could help out.

Comment: I don´t think bound parameters in the SELECT clause is valid in MySQL: `(SELECT @params) `

Comment: @Alex B. Oh ok. I wasn't too sure. Thought it was something wrong I was doing. I'll share some snapshots later on. Thanks for your input.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34750246/1070452) sounds very similar to your problem

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for that. I just viewed it and your method makes absolute sense. I'll implement and get back to you.

Comment: @Plutonix VS underlines `GetFullCommandSQL(comA)` as error. What am I missing? I really want to be able to display my full 'sql code' myself for debug purpose. Thanks

Comment: just leave that part out - it wasnt as useful as it sounds except to see if the right number of parameters were being passed for the IN clause. [Get it from here](http://pastebin.com/NwKL2Lz1) if you are curious. Please upvote the answer if it helps

Comment: Wow @Plutonix!!! Your `GetFullCommandSQL` function works as seen in the debugger, although I haven't tried `ExecuteNonQuery()` yet. My SQL Code looks as expected. I guess this answers my question already. THANKS A LOT!