# MySQL paramaterized query with arbitrary number of variables in the "IN" section

Tags: c#, mysql

I am struggling with the MySQL paramaterized query I am trying to write.  It has "WHERE IN" in the conditions and I want to pass it a list of strings.  First I tried passing it one comma seperated string to the paramater.  But everything after the first value did not work.  I assume it stripped the commas and everything after the comma.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT itemref, name FROM cart_item ci WHERE ci.itemref IN (?itemrefstring) AND (quantity < 5 OR active = 0);
```

Now I am passing a commma seperated values string into itemrefstring.  That did not work.  I tried passing the list of strings to that parameter.  That did not work either.

Comment: I think you have to build a query in string and execute it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameterize an SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause)

Comment: Check out @MarkBrackett 's answer in the duplicate topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/5389997

Comment: [Dynamic Delete query with multiple values IN(...) clause](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34750246/1070452)   Its in VB but otherwise pretty much the same issue